# Linking jQuery Cycle Pager element

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery Cycle plugin with pagers. I need to have navigation functionality, where I can provide a link to my client and he can browse that page which is a projects gallery. I need the cycle plugin to show a particular slide. Maybe variables can be supplied in the URL to go to a specific slide. I do not mind writing another jquery script to achieve it.

In that case, I would need to get a variable on pageload from the URL (a number 'n') and make a click on a nth element inside a div.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following to get the parameter from the query string:

```
 function $_GET(q,s) {
   s = (s) ? s : window.location.search; 
   var re = new RegExp('&amp;'+q+'=([^&amp;]*)','i');
   return (s=s.replace(/^\?/,'&amp;').match(re)) ?s=s[1] :s='';
 }
```

Then in the cycle declaration you can use `startingSlide` (assuming the number was in the parameter `param_num`:

```
 $.cycle({
     startingSlide: $_GET('param_num'),
     // rest of your cycle config
 });
```

One thing to note that [startingSlide](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/options.html) is zero-based index, so the number you pass in the parameter should reflect that.